# How to slowly add to an objects Z scale on a button press unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform

I'm trying to make a game where you drive a little car, and when you press a button, say C, wings come out and you can fly. I'm thinking the best way to do this would have a capsule scaled to look like rounded wings as a child of the car. The Z scale of these wings is normally small enough that you can't see them (0.01), but when you press C, the Z value slowly increases until it reaches a certain point (in my case 0.0435) All I'm getting now is an error saying "Cannot modify the return value of 'Transform.localScale' because it is not a variable."

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RocketorCar : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform wings;
    public Rigidbody rb;

    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKey("c")){
            if(wings.localScale.z = 0.01f){
                wings.localScale = wings.localScale + new Vector3(0, 0, 0.0335f);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error is that you use **1** equal sign, but you want **2** equal signs for comparing, e.g. `==`:

```
if (wings.localScale.z == 0.01f) { /* ... */ } // you want to compare
```

The error is misleading, as you assign with one equal sign, the error is because since `localScale` is a struct, you must introduce a local variable from it, change its value, then assign it back to `localScale`:

```
var localScale = wings.localScale;
localScale.z = 0.01f;
wings.localScale = localScale;
```

Back to your problem, you'll then get a warning about floating point comparison,

Here's a better approach in comparing them:

```
if (Mathf.Approximately(wings.localScale.z, 0.01f))
{
    // ...       
}
```

---

**EDIT**

Scales your wings, change as you see fit:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Scaler : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform[] Wings;                                              // drag your wings here in inspector
    public KeyCode     WingScaleKeyUp     = KeyCode.KeypadPlus;            // scale up key
    public KeyCode     WingScaleKeyUpDown = KeyCode.KeypadMinus;           // scale down key
    public Vector3     WingScaleFactor    = new Vector3(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f); // scale step
    public Vector3     WingScaleSpeed     = new Vector3(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f); // scale speed
    public Vector3     WingScaleMin       = new Vector3(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f); // scale min
    public Vector3     WingScaleMax       = new Vector3(2.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f); // scale max

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Wings == null)
            return;

        foreach (var target in Wings)
        {
            var p = Input.GetKey(WingScaleKeyUp) ? +1.0f : Input.GetKey(WingScaleKeyUpDown) ? -1.0f : 0.0f;
            var q = target.localScale;
            var r = Vector3.Scale(WingScaleFactor, WingScaleSpeed * p); // scale axes independently
            var s = q + r;
            var x = Mathf.Max(WingScaleMin.x, Mathf.Min(WingScaleMax.x, s.x)); // restrict
            var y = Mathf.Max(WingScaleMin.y, Mathf.Min(WingScaleMax.y, s.y));
            var z = Mathf.Max(WingScaleMin.z, Mathf.Min(WingScaleMax.z, s.z));

            target.localScale = new Vector3(x, y, z);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: that worked great! I fixed the if statement with your suggestion then used Easwar Chinrajs idea for the changing. I copied the 3 lines that Easwar Chinraj suggested and changed the += to -=, but it only changes the size once, from 0.01 to 0.0435 or from 0.0435 to 0.01. How can I make it so that it changes to the next size whenever I press the button instead of once?

Comment: sorry, let me clarify: I want to be able to press C once, and the size changes, depending on where it was before. If it was at 0.0435 and I press C, it goes to 0.01. If it was at 0.01 and I press C, it goes to 0.0435, without me having to hold the key. maybe just a check for if the size is 0.01 and I press c, it transitions to 0.0435, and vice-versa? I have no idea how to do that, I'm too beginner for that lol.

Comment: You could use something like `Mathf.MoveTowards`.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works:

```
Vector3 tempScale = wings.localScale;
tempScale.z += 0.0335f;
wings.localScale = tempScale;
```